# Blob field in MySQL DB

Tags: java, mysql

I have a public key value that I want to store it in DB. I stored it as Blob. The Java concerned lines are:

```
byte[] pk = ((BigInteger) Modulus ).toByteArray();
```

and

```
preparedStmt.setBytes(1, pk);
```

When I open MySQL DB in the workbench GUI, I don't see the value itself as bytes. Rather, I see the following:

[image]

Not sure if this is how it should appear or there is something missing.

Comment: If you want to make sure about the data, retrieve it using another tool and transforming the bytes into something like a String or a file or whatever you need it.

Comment: I retrieved this field back to BIGINT using Java & I got the correct value. But when I opened the workbench, I had doubt that there is something wrong. I want to make sure.

Comment: No need to worry then. Its just that the BLOB data can be very large to show it in a cell